# error during Xcode build: cannot specify both '-fobjc-arc' and '-fobjc-gc'

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I've just downloaded a fresh codebase from SF, with a product set to target 10.8. It was written in the GC era.

When I build, I get this error:

> cannot specify both '-fobjc-arc' and '-fobjc-gc'

ARC is turned off in both the target and project settings. None of the files have any flags in Build Phases.

So where is this flag turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable or enable ARC according to the picture below.

[image: Enable/Disable ARC]

To Enable ARC add `f-objc-arc` to the compiler flag of your implementation file or `fno-objc-arc` to disable it!

Hope it helps!

Comment: That did it! But frankly, using the setting in the Built Settings should be enough. I'll report that as a bug.